# How to configure Lotus Notes to not show images in emails?

Tags: email, lotus-notes

Is it possible to configure Lotus Notes to not show images in emails?  Some external image links contain tracking data and I'd rather not let spammers know I've got their messages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disclaimer: I'm not a Lotus Notes user. I found this workaround [here](http://searchdomino.techtarget.com/tip/0,289483,sid4_gci1041376,00.html):

> You can block these external images
>   from loading by editing your current
>   location document (bottom right of
>   your screen, select Edit Current...)
>   and specifying a proxy server of
>   0.0.0.0:80.
>
> This tells Notes to use a non-existent
>   proxy server to load the images.

Edit: which version are you using? Version 8 seems to implement this feature:

[image: Lotus Notes screenshot]

See here: [Discovering Notes 8: Automatic loading of images in HTML newsletters](http://lekkimworld.com/2007/10/05/discovering_notes_8_automatic_loading_of_images_in_html_newsletters.html)